# Does bokeh hijack the DOM so I can't change it using CustomJS?

Tags: python, html, dom, bokeh

Why doesn't this work?

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput, Button
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS

# Create html page with a button and a textinput
bt = Button(label='Remove the text field!')
ti = TextInput(title='A text input field')

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(ti=ti), code=""" ti.parentNode.removeChild(ti); """)
bt.js_on_click(callback)
ly = column([bt, ti])

# Write to file
html = file_html(ly, CDN, "my page")
with open('/path/to/file.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(html)
```

It makes a webpage with a button and a text field. When you click the button, the text field is supposed to disappear.

The callback is indeed getting called (which you can tell by replacing the argument code with code="ti.placeholder='something'", for example, and you see the placeholder text change).

Is bokeh hijacking my ability to change the DOM? And more to the point, how do I use CustomJS to add/delete/replace widgets? I can't use the regular python methods of replacing widgets because I can't run a server. I just have to have all the widget add/delete/replace action hard-coded in Javascript so that it runs on a standalone local html page with no server.

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh does not hijack the DOM, you can access and manipulate the DOM however you like from a `CustomJS` callback, or any other JS code. However, in your code above `ti` is not a DOM element, which is why passing it to `removeChild` has no effect.

Instead, `ti` is a *Bokeh Model*, which is an object that among other things, knows how to automatically synchronize to its Python counterpart in a Bokeh server context. The `ti` model has a *view*, which does have a DOM element. I suppose you could try to remove that by hand with JS DOM calls, but I would not recommend it. That would not clean up the model, which might still respond to various events and would probably be a source of subtle problems. Additionally there's not an easy way to get at the view, you'd have to search the entire DOM for it (views have references to their models, but models do not have references to any views).

If using a Bokeh server, I'd suggest just updating the `column` children to remove the text input model. But I can't get something similar working from pure JS in a `CustomJS` callback, which may indicate a bug. In general, Bokeh was created with static widget layouts in mind, trying to add and remove widgets is definitely pushing the envelope. At present I would suggest that if you want that level of control you might consider creating a Custom Extension that encapsulates the DOM management in the JS implementation of your custom model:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html

Comment: Interesting thanks. Yeah that's the problem, I'm not (and can't, due to dependencies) using a Bokeh server. Interesting, thanks for the link about extensions. I'll poke around some more

Comment: @bigreddot does that mean that one bokeh model may be bound to more than one view? If not, why wouldn't view be accessible from the bokeh model? Has anything been updated in that field since you posted this answer? Accessing DOM from js callbacks would be amazing - there can be so much more done than deleting the DOM elements.